# Partition points on a 2d plane with arbitrary line segment

Tags: computational-geometry

Let's say I have a 11x11 grid with a few points (around 8) marked in the grid. One of the points is in the center cell. Call it point P.

I choose a point other than P and connect it with a line segment to P. Call that point C1

I choose another point that is not C1 and connect it with a line segment to P. Call that point C2.

Now, if we extend the line segments out from P to the edges of the grid, then the grid will be split into two regions A and B.

How can I determine which of the remaining points are in A and B efficiently?

Comment: I thought of connecting the test point to C1 and C2 and then defining the sets A and B as:
A: resulting polygon is convex.
B: polygon is complex or simple concave

Comment: If it is only $8$, then best bet is prolly brute force checking; it is an interesting question for arbitrary number of points.

Comment: For such a tiny number of points, just brute-force it. For the more general problem, look up "Half-space range searching" in computational geometry.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Instead of storing them as [cartesian points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_coordinates), store them as [polar coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinates) (with a tiny drop of preprocessing).